# Session popup window

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want the popup to be displayed only once the window loads, but iam unable to find the solution.
Below is the source code:

```html
<?php 
$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$course = $_POST['course'];


$formcontent='<html>
    <head>
        <title>Message</title>
        <style type="text/css">
           body { background-color: lightgray;padding:20px;margin:0px auto;width:50%;border-radius:10px; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
 <h2 style="color:#FAB702;text-align:center;">Thorsignia</h2>
        <p><strong style="color:#000000;">Name:  </strong> '.$name.'</p>
        <p><strong style="color:#000000;">Phone:  </strong> '.$phone.'</p>
        <p><strong style="color:#000000;">Email:  </strong>'.$email.'</p>
        <p><strong style="color:#000000;">Course:  </strong>'.$course.'</p>
    </body>
</html>';


$recipient = "abc@xyz.com";
$subject = "Customer Enquiry";
$mailheader = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$mailheader .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$mailheader .= "From: $email \r\n";

if(mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader)){
 
 echo "<script>
             alert('Your Message sent successfully, We will revert back to you soon, Thank you!'); 
             window.history.go(-1);
     </script>";
 
}else{
 
 echo "<script>
             alert('Something went wrong, check contact form again!!'); 
             window.history.go(-1);
     </script>";
}


 // header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

?>
```

So i need only the popup to be displayed once as the window load in, that is i need to maintain a session , so please help me as how to maintain the session.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Create a session after sending message and check the session is set or not. if Session is set pop up the window and unset the session with in the  condition. `

```
// check if session is not set
if(!isset($_SESSION['seesion_name'])) { `
   // code here to poup the window 
   $_SESSION['seesion_name'] == True; // set session if popup shown once
} `
```